# Adding images by combining cells with Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, cell

*First of all, I have difficulty in explaining because my English is not very good. But I will try to explain as best I can.*

I add random photos to the canvasta cells fields with Javascript.

Each plot is equivalent to 20pixels. What I want to do is:
if i and y in the map data are equal to 4;
I want to add the photo I want to a 4x4 area.

In other words, while adding a photo to 20 pixels;
I want to add a photo to a 320pixel area when it is 4x4.

As in the sample photo.
[Check Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PAth.png)

[image]

```js
var map = [
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ];
        
        window.onload = function() {
            const canvas = document.getElementById("main");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "transparent";
            ctx.lineWidth = 0;

            
            //draw grid
            for (let i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
                const x = i*20;
                ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
                ctx.stroke();
                
                const y = i*20;
                ctx.moveTo(0, y);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            
            
            //draw images
            const p = ctx.lineWidth / 1; //padding
            for (let xCell = 0; xCell < map.length; xCell++) {
                for (let yCell = 0; yCell < map[xCell].length; yCell++) {
                    const x = xCell * 20;
                    const y = yCell * 20;
                    const img = new Image();
                    if (map[xCell][yCell] === 1) {
                        img.onload = function() {
                            ctx.drawImage(img, y+p, x+p, 20-p*2, 20-p*2);
                        };
                        
                        //TODO: set img.src to your api url instead of the dummyimage url.
                        img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}/200/300`;
                    }else if(map[xCell][yCell] == 4){
                        img.onload = function() {
                            ctx.drawImage(img, y+p, x+p, 20-p*2, 20-p*2);
                        };
                        
                        //TODO: set img.src to your api url instead of the dummyimage url.
                        img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}/200/300`;
                    }
                
                }
            }
        };
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="600" height="630"></canvas>
        
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Ibrahim, is it possible to convert your shared code into a snippet which reproduces the behavior you have? It would make it easier to us to experiment with it in order to find a solution for you.

Comment: Yes of course you can reuse my code.

Comment: I was meaning that you could click on the create snippet button while you edit your question, add some HTML and test it so that it produces the behavior you have.

Comment: I fixed it. Now you can run it again.

Comment: Thanks, I have written an answer, maybe it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as below. *There are positional errors but I will completely fix them.*

Thanks to **Lajos Arpad** for trying to help.

```js
var defaultMap = [
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            ];
            var images = [
                {
                    name: "player 1",
                    position: [
                        {
                            x: [0,4],
                            y: [4,4]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "player 2",
                    position: [
                        {
                            x: [5,7],
                            y: [5,2]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];
            
            window.onload = function() {
                const canvas = document.getElementById("main");
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.strokeStyle = "transparent";
                ctx.lineWidth = 0;

                
                //draw grid
                for (let i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
                    const x = i*40;
                    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    
                    const y = i*40;
                    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
                    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                
                const p = ctx.lineWidth / 1;
                for (let xCell = 0; xCell < defaultMap.length; xCell++) {
                    for (let yCell = 0; yCell < defaultMap[xCell].length; yCell++) {
                        const x = xCell * 20;
                        const y = yCell * 20;
                        const img = new Image();
                        if (defaultMap[xCell][yCell] === 1) {
                            img.onload = function() {
                                ctx.drawImage(img, y+p, x+p, 20-p*2, 20-p*2);
                            };
                            
                            img.src = `https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/5-6-2020/134999/thumb-black-ground-texture-macro-grunge-textures-black-backgrounds-ground-textures.jpg`;
                        }
                    
                    }
                }

                for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    var width = 1, height = 1, x = images[i].position[0].x[0], y = images[i].position[0].y[0];
                    console.log(images[i].name + " x => " + images[i].position[0].x[0])
                    for(let w = images[i].position[0].x[0]; w < images[i].position[0].x[1]; w++){
                        width++
                    }
                    
                    for(let h = 1; h < images[i].position[0].y[1]; h++){
                        height++
                    }
                    const img = new Image();
                    img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}/200/300`;
                    img.onload = function() {
                        console.log(20*images[i].position[0].x[0]+p)
                        /* ctx.rect(20*i, 20*i, 20*width-p*2, 20*height-p*2)
                        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                        ctx.fill(); */
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 20*images[i].position[0].y[0]+p, 20*images[i].position[0].x[0]+p, 20*width-p*2, 20*height-p*2);
                    };
                    
                }
            };
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="600" height="630"></canvas>
        
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the value of a multiplier and use that to determine the picture size.

```js
var map = [
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ];
        
        window.onload = function() {
            const canvas = document.getElementById("main");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "transparent";
            ctx.lineWidth = 0;

            
            //draw grid
            for (let i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
                const x = i*20;
                ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
                ctx.stroke();
                
                const y = i*20;
                ctx.moveTo(0, y);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            
            
            //draw images
            const p = ctx.lineWidth / 1; //padding
            for (let xCell = 0; xCell < map.length; xCell++) {
                for (let yCell = 0; yCell < map[xCell].length; yCell++) {
                    let multiplier = ((map[xCell][yCell] % 4) ? 1 : 4);
                    const x = xCell * 20;
                    const y = yCell * 20;
                    const img = new Image();
                    if (map[xCell][yCell] === 1) {
                        img.onload = function() {
                            ctx.drawImage(img, y+p, x+p, multiplier * 20-p*2, multiplier * 20-p*2);
                        };
                        
                        //TODO: set img.src to your api url instead of the dummyimage url.
                        img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}/200/300`;
                    }else if(map[xCell][yCell] == 4){
                        img.onload = function() {
                            ctx.drawImage(img, y+p, x+p, multiplier * 20-p*2, multiplier * 20-p*2);
                        };
                        
                        //TODO: set img.src to your api url instead of the dummyimage url.
                        img.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)}/200/300`;
                    }
                
                }
            }
        };
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="600" height="630"></canvas>
        
    </canvas>
```

Comment: But this adds multiple photo frames. So what I want is to add a single photo to a 4x4 area. So think of it as a map. After you draw one edge of the map, the other edge will be larger and that edge will look like 1px but will take up a larger area.

Comment: @ibrahim I'm afraid I do not understand your point. My understanding was that every 4-valued element should have a bigger size. If this is misunderstood on my part, then which image should have a bigger size?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/PrfN334/image-1.png Check out the photo here. What I want is exactly this;
A photo is added to the 20x20 area. 20x20pixel is equivalent to 1 parcel.
What I want is: 20x4x4 (4 pieces of 20 pixels from right to left and 4 pieces of 20 pixels from left to bottom) I want to add 1 photo to this 4x4 area.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/9gjQK7z/image.png I want to explain with another example. I want to do as you see here.

Comment: @v-Cx so you will have images inside images. A square of 4s represents a square of 4x4 units. In such a place you need to display a single image for the 4x4 units, ignoring the others? Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I can sum it up like this. If all numbers in a 4x4 area are 4, a single large image will be added to that area.

Comment: @v-Cx I see. So basically my solution correctly displays the left-top image and incorrectly displays the 15 other images that are to its close proximity (to the right or bottom of the left-top image). So, is it correct to assume that if I avoid displaying the 15 other images in that rectangle, then the resulting script would be correct? If yes, I will do an edit. If no, then I would need further information.

Comment: I would like to give detailed information and summarize as follows.

Each frame you see consists of 20pixels. What I want to do is add a 320pixel photo in a 4x4 area.

I saw a very good example of this.

Sandbox's map site has exactly the example I want.

https://www.sandbox.game/en/map here

Comment: The layout of the squares and the map will be exactly like this. So what I'm trying to do is exactly something like this. @Lajos Arpad

Comment: Some photos will take up 1x1 parcel, some parcels will take up 4x4 parcels, some will take up 12x12 parcels.

Comment: Lajos Arpad thank you for all your help. I fixed my problem.

Comment: @v-Cx I'm happy that you have successfully resolved it!